# Json ObjectMapper unable to read Json value

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a enum class

```
public enum CacheType {
    NONE("none"), NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE("nonrestrictreadwrite"), READ_ONLY("readonly"), READ_WRITE("readwrite");

    private final String text;

    private CacheType(final String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    @JsonValue
    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Now i have Table class

```
public class Table {
    private CacheType cachetype;
    .... getters and setters
}
```

Now if the json is sent to spring controller the `Table` is constructed properly with `cachetype` set. Till now everything is okay.

Now i am doing `Unit Test` so i read the json test file like follows and convert it to Object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
table= mapper.readValue(file, Table.class);
```

Here the `cachetype` is always set to `NULL`. Rest of the Table attributes are set properly. How can i read `cachetype` properly

```
{
 "tables":[
   {
      "name": "DummyUsers",
      "namespace": "",
      "cachetype": "readwrite"
   },
   {
      "name": "AdminUsers",
      "namespace": "",
      "cachetype": "nonrestrictreadwrite"
   },
   {
      "name": "SuperUsers",
      "namespace": "",
      "cachetype": "none"
   }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide the JSON test file?

Comment: added my json file contents

Comment: Which Jackson version? Does it not work with 2.5.3? Some earlier versions only used `@JsonValue` for serialization, but later ones should accept it for deserialization as well.